# Trouble querying a certain value from Salesforce PHP API

Tags: php

so I have a script on a page on my website that connects to my SF, queries for a certain value, and returns the value. It looks like it should work, but I'm not seeing anything. $user is set, and the password, security token, and username is valid and functional. It connects fine too - I omitted all that code because it is not relevant.

```
$query = "SELECT Account.Webpage_Link__c FROM Account WHERE Name = '".$name."'";
$response = $sf->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {
    $WebpageLink = $record->Webpage_Link__c;
}
echo $WebpageLink;
```

The `$name` is exactly the same as an Account Name in Salesforce, so that's not an issue either. Any help?

**Edit:**

I think the issue is within the query itself. I'm outputting the entire $record object using print_r(). For some reason the ID and Name will output fine, but my custom field (using the exact field name from SF) doesn't play nice.

Comment: Could you pls try once just putting name where clause not variable ?

Comment: $User has a specific meaning as a global variable in Salesforce with respect to Users, not Accounts, so it's a very relevant question for @PrabhatKumar to ask you to clarify. In essence, what exactly is Salesforce going to receive on their end? How are you sending this? I don't know that you're providing adequate info for anyone to properly answer your question.

Comment: They're receiving an Account Name. And $user is not the variable actually in my code, it's just what I put here. The query should match the account name that matches the variable, then pull the Webpage_Link__c

Comment: @crmprogdev...I think $user variable here stands for a string value. Akor must be assigning a string in $user variable.  Not a global variable of salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my Enterprise WSDL was not updated since before I added the custom field. Updated it and all my queries work fine.

See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm